# Moving the 1st item of an alphabetical list in Order By to the end

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

ou.ShortName contains a list of states and simply putting it in the Order By clause alphabetizes the list.

```
929285  Alaska  2014-04-01 12:00:00.000
931104  Alaska  2014-04-02 12:00:00.000
931106  Alaska  2014-04-03 17:00:00.000
931253  Alaska  2014-04-15 20:30:00.000
929320  Arizona 2014-04-02 15:30:00.000
929322  Arizona 2014-04-08 15:30:00.000
929324  Arizona 2014-04-09 15:30:00.000
929326  Arizona 2014-04-16 15:30:00.000
```

But the end user wants Alaska, and only Alaska, moved to the end of the list. This seems like something I could do in the Order By with a Case statement but I'm stumped on how to do it.

```
order by 
Case
        when ou.ShortName = 'Alaska'
        then ?????
        Else ou.ShortName
End as States
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple clauses in an `order by`:

```
order by (case when ou.ShortName = 'Alaska' then 1 else 0 end),
         ou.ShortName
```

By the way, `as` doesn't belong in an `order by` clause.  It will just generate an error.